# Unable to handle Basic Authentication windows

Tags: ruby, watir, autoit

Iam working on Popup windows i.e. handling Basic Authentication windows.Please find the below code which I am trying to run the test with

```
{

require 'watir/ie'

require 'win32ole'

require 'watir/WindowHelper'

ie=Watir::IE.new

ie.goto "http://www.google.com"

helper = WindowHelper.new

helper.logon('Connect to proxy1','Mohammed','WE8SR')        # where title=Connect to Proxy1 is the auth window,User name= Mohammed and Password=WE8SR.
puts x.inspect

ie.close

}
```

What happens is the User Name and Password is never typed in the Authentication Window and `Timedout Error` is displayed.

```
ruby google_search.rb 
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:494:in sleep': execution expired (Timeout::Error) 
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:494:in block in wait' 
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:491:in wait' 
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:357:in goto' 
from google_search.rb:96:in `<main>' 
>Exit code: 1
```

Is this the problem with the version of **Ruby 1.9.2** which I am using?

I modified the code for a method `logon` in the `WindowHelper.rb` and tried doing it.

```
// Actual method in the "WindowHelper.rb" file
{

    def logon(title,name = 'john doe',password = 'john doe')

        @autoit.WinWait title, ""

        @autoit.Send name

        @autoit.Send "{TAB}"

        @autoit.Send password

        @autoit.Send "{ENTER}"

    end
 }
```

Code which I modified to and found working sometimes

```
{

        def logon(title,name,password)

        @autoit.WinWait title, ""

        @autoit.Send name

        @autoit.Send "{TAB}"

        @autoit.Send password

        @autoit.Send "{ENTER}"

    end

}
```

I have tried for the solution in various blogs. Suggest me if I am missing something.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused, when I login at google it doesn't pop up a separate window for authentication.   Is this some windows level authentication that is imposed by the IT folks at your site, to gain access to a proxy server or something?

Comment: can you give the error text for the timeout error?

Comment: Hi Chuck,

In my case I do have a windows level authentication done by the local IT team to gain access to a proxy server, i.e. the reason I get this authentication window.

Below error message is displayed and the execution never happens.

Comment: >ruby google_search.rb

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:494:in `sleep': execution expired (Timeout::Error)
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:494:in `block in wait'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:491:in `wait'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:357:in `goto'
 from google_search.rb:96:in `<main>'

>Exit code: 1

Comment: You know as the author you should be able to edit the original question right?

Comment: I donot understand what you are referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to editing the content of your original question to include requested information as opposed to trying to present it in comments where it cannot be properly formatted.  If you look just below the tags on your question above you should see an 'edit' button.  When someone asks for additional info, you can edit the question to include it, which generally works a lot better than trying to put it in a comment.  (this is one of the things that makes Stackoverflow so nice for support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your script stopped before handling BASIC Authentication because your error text said Timeout error occured at wait method which is used in goto method.

try ie.navigate method instead of goto method like the following

```
require 'watir/ie'
require 'win32ole'
require 'watir/WindowHelper'

ie=Watir::IE.new

ie.ie.navigate "http://www.google.com"

helper = WindowHelper.new

helper.logon('Connect to proxy1','Mohammed','WE8SR')        # where title=Connect to Proxy1 is the auth window,User name= Mohammed and Password=WE8SR.
puts x.inspect

ie.close
```

Comment: On Using "ie.ie.navigate "http://www.google.com"", Authentication window is handled, A Blank page is displayed producing the following error message :
>ruby google_search.rb
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:403:in `method_missing': unknown property or method: `hwnd' (NoMethodError)
    HRESULT error code:0x800706ba
      The RPC server is unavailable.
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-1.7.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:403:in `close'
 from google_search.rb:107:in `<main>'
#<WindowHelper:0x1356d50 @autoit=#<WIN32OLE:0x1356cd8>>
nil
>Exit code: 1

Comment: That worked beautifully by modifying the code as :

require 'watir/ie'
require 'win32ole'
require 'watir/WindowHelper'

ie=Watir::IE.new
ie.ie.navigate "http://www.google.com"
helper = WindowHelper.new
puts helper.inspect
x=helper.logon('Connect to fproxy1','Mohammed.Ali1','WE8SRgmC')
puts x.inspect
ie.ie.navigate "http://www.yahoo.com"
ie.close


Thanks a lot Yutaka.

ajazz.